# Selenium Hub Chrome Node does not get HttpOnly Cookies

Tags: c#, selenium, cookies, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-hub

I am running Selenium tests in two ways:

1. locally with Chrome WebDriver, for implementing the tests
2. in a CI-pipeline with Selenium Hub and a Chrome Node, to run the tests

The backend creates HttpOnly cookies. I want to check their existence. To get a specific cookie I use the following code:

```
driver.Manage().Cookies.GetCookieNamed("CookieFooBar");
```

This works perfectly with the Chrome WebDriver, but does not work with the Chrome Node. Any ideas, what might cause this different behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this problem is already inside the question itself. As the cookies are HttpOnly cookies, the browser can't track their existence - nevertheless they are still existing. This is actually the reason the HttpOnly flag was created for.

For testing purposes it might be a better approach to test the functionality the cookies should provide instead of simply checking their existence.

I ran the Chrome WebDriver tests without a docker-compose, which I did in the CI-pipeline. That is why the browser was not able to see the HttpOnly cookies.